# Is it possible to use a self certified SSL certificate on XAMPP that can be used with telegram bot webhooks

Tags: ssl, telegram-bot

**Is it possible to use a self certified SSL certificate on XAMPP that can be used with telegram bot webhooks?** I am trying to set up my telegram bot, I am currently using "getupdates" method. Therefore I am trying to set up webhooks but it dosent work. **Does anyone have experience or advice on using webhooks with XAMPP?**

I am using the example telegram code shown [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples/hellobot)

{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook is already set"}